# Kernels and Direct Products in $\mathbb{Z}_q$

Tags: linear-algebra, modules

Let $q$ be an integer not necessarily prime. In the sequel we denote by $A || B$ the concatenation of the columns of some matrices $A,B$.  Suppose that the three full rank matrices $M, M_0, M_1$ are in $\mathbb{Z}_q^{3k \times k}$ such that $M||M_0||M_1$ spans $\mathbb{Z}_q^{3k}$.
Is it true in general that:

$$ \ker (M^\top) = \ker ((M||M_0)^\top) \oplus \ker ((M||M_1)^\top) $$

Note that one direction is easily shown since an element of the direct sum will naturally be in the kernel, which gives us that $ 
\ker ((M||M_0)^\top) \oplus \ker ((M||M_1)^\top) \subseteq \ker (M^\top) $.
The reverse direction is easy to show in the case that $q$ is prime via a dimension argument, which I believe breaks down when $\mathbb{Z}_q$ is not a field.

Any ideas? The context is from [this paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/094.pdf) in Lemma 8

Comment: What does $\|$ mean here?

Comment: @MorganRodgers yes exactly it is the matrix obtained by concatenating the columns of the matrices

Comment: In that case, what does it mean that $M||M_0||M_1$ spans $\mathbb{Z}_q^{3k}$? How can a single matrix (which lies in $\Bbb Z_q^{3k\times 3k}$, not $\Bbb Z_q^{3k}$) span all of that? Do you mean that it's non-singular? That the _columns_ span $\Bbb Z_q^{3k}$?

Comment: @Arthur the column space of the matrix equals $\mathbf{Z}_q^3k$ which in the prime case amounts to say that the columns are all linearly independent but in the q composite case is slightly more complex since having a set of 3k LI vectors does not automatically gives you a basis

Comment: Fair enough. I just had some comprehension issues when you said that the matrix spans the space rather than the columns of the matrix. Wanted to clarify.